# Getting Button state in XCUITest

Tags: xctest

How to get button state in XCUITest?

It is just a NSButton which acts as a toggle button. The images changes upon clicking. In application i check with button.state which returns 0 or 1. depending upon the values i changes the images.

```
@IBAction func checkBoxClick(sender: NSButton) {
    print("Checkbox state ", sender.state)
}
```

But when writing XCUITest automaton code, i am not able to get the state of the button. there is no attribute like state. Also when i take 'value' or 'selected' attributes of the button it always gives nil and false.

```
let window = XCUIApplication().windows["Window"]
    let button = window.buttons["Button"]
    button.click()
    print("Button selected ",button.selected)
    print("Button selected value ",button.value)
    button.click()
    print("Button unselected ",button.selected)
    print("Button unselected value ",button.value)
```

Values printed are

```
Button selected  false
Button selected value  nil
Button unselected  false
Button unselected value  nil
```

Any inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application code, you could map the 0/1 state to selected/not selected. Default state should be false and when it is toggled, invert the state of `sender.selected`.

The `selected` property represents two states and provides the same functionality as your `.state` addition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I did like this
 if (tempButton.state == NSOnState) {
            tempButton.setAccessibilitySelected(true)
        } else {
            tempButton.setAccessibilitySelected(false)
        }
is this what you suggested. and it is working with above code

Comment: Slightly different to what I said but good solution - probably the better way TBH. :)